# Should html header tag only contain info common to all pages

Tags: html

My *header* tag contains an image (logo) which is common to all pages and then page *title* which is different for each page. Suddenly occurred to me that perhaps only the image should be part of the header tag and title shoud go in the body tag ?

e.g

```
<header>
    <img srcset="style/songkongheader.png 400w,style/songkongheader-medium.png 200w,style/songkongheader-small.png 100w," sizes="(max-width:800px) 200px,(max-width:600px) 100px,400px" class="mb-2">
    <h2 class="subheading ui-corner-all" title="Undo Fixes">
        <a style="text-decoration: none">
            Undo Fixes
        </a>
    </h2>
</header>
```

Could someone please clarify

Comment: At the end of the day, it's all just preference, right? I mean the header tag is just a div tag with a different name so you have a better idea of what it's for. See the [Header tag MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)

Comment: I dont see why put on hold, it should realy be clear which defintion of header is correct, if not then that is worthy of discussion in itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using the `<header>` now seems to be perfectly valid and correct.
According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header):

> The `<header>` element is not sectioning content and therefore does not introduce a new section in the outline. That said, a `<header>` element ***is intended to usually contain the surrounding section's heading*** (an h1–h6 element), but this is *not* required.

And they provide a `Page Header` example (which is 100% your case):

```
<header>
  <h1>Main Page Title</h1>
  <img src="mdn-logo-sm.png" alt="MDN logo">
</header>
```